# how can I handle response error in expo app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, server, expo

I'm working on an app using React Native and Expo. I'm not new to react native, but this is the first job that required the use of expo. My problem is I'm sending error messages from the server that would be usefull for front end logic, but expo constantly overrides the error with an error that Expo generates, and I can't figure out how to retreive the message from the server.

Server code:

```
...Random server logic
return res.status(400).json({ msg: "invalid user credentials" });
```

What I receive in the expo app.

```
message(pin):"Request failed with status code 402"
name(pin):"Error"
stack(pin):"Error: Request failed with status code 402 at createError (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:176428:17) at settle (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:176418:14) at EventTarget.handleLoad (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:176316:9) at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:32785:27) at EventTarget.setReadyState (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:31854:14) at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:31696:16) at http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:31806:47 at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:7450:37) at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:3225:44) at http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:2938:17"
```

Comment: 402 error is payment required. Maybe you need pay expo or some other service you're using?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/402

Comment: Yea I should have mentioned that... I briefly changed the status from 400 to a random other status just to see if I was getting anything back from the server. It was getting back the proper status, but anything I put in json or plain text gets lost somewhere.